# mpfr'izing a data.frame in R

Tags: r, floating-point, mpfr

I'm trying to convert a data.frame in R to mpfr format by multiplying by an mpfr unit constant. This works, as demonstrated in the code below, when applied to a column (result variable 'mpfr_col'), but for both approaches shown for working with a data.frame, it does not. The relevant errors for each attempt are listed in comment.

```
library(Rmpfr)

prec <- 256
m1 <- mpfr(1,prec)
col_build <- 1:10
test_df <- data.frame(col_build, col_build, col_build)
mpfr_col <- m1*(col_build)
mpfr_df <- m1*test_df # (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

for(colnum in 1:length(colnames(test_df))){
  test_df[,colnum] <- m1*test_df[,colnum] # attempt to replicate an object of type 'S4'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer:

Use `[[colnum]]` to access the columns instead of `[,colnum]`:

```
for(colnum in length(colnames(test_df))){
  test_df[[colnum]] <- m1*test_df[[colnum]] 
}
```

(Note: the `print` method of `data.frame` will fail, but the 'mpfr-izing' work. You can print it either by printing the columns individually or using `as_tibble(test_df)`.

### Explanation

The original fails because the `[,colnum]` assignment doesn't coerce the argument, I think. Using `[[` returns an element (aka a column) of the list (aka the data.frame).

See this bit of Hadley Wickham's [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html#subsetting-answers) book:

> 2. [ selects sub-lists. It always returns a list; if you use it with a
>      single positive integer, it returns a list of length one. [[ selects
>      an element within a list. $ is a convenient shorthand: x$y is
>      equivalent to x[["y"]].

And the help from `Extract.data.frame {base}`:

> When [ and [[ are used to add or replace a whole column, no coercion
>   takes place but value will be replicated (by calling the generic
>   function rep) to the right length if an exact number of repeats can be
>   used.